# Where do I store div's for jQuery Mobile pop-up

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, layout, popup

Okay this has to be the simplest thing in the world but I just can't figure it out.
I have read the documentation and understand the concept of a JQM pop-up.

a link with:

```
href="popupBasic" data-rel="popup"
```

and a div with:

```
data-role="popup" id="popupBasic"
```

What I don't understand is where do I store that div because if it is in the html file the div content shows up without needing the pop-up and makes no sesnse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out I was wrong and was a formatting issue you can store div's on local HTML document without them showing.

Knew it was simple.

Thanks anyway :).